# Unable to load workflow actions from the server. Please contact your server administrator: Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I try to open a workflow using Designer 2013. I get the error "Unable to load workflow actions from the server. Please contact your server administrator".

I did a lots of digging and not able to find a good solution for this.

One option was to see if there's a solution deployed in both the farm level and site collection level. But there's nothing.

I checked the logs but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

When we try to open the workflows in the SharePoint Designer, sometimes we receive the below error:

[image]

**Symptoms**:

You can access the workflow from the SharePoint UI. Other workflows in different web applications are editable.

**Cause**:

Cannot be same in all the scenarios but should be specific to the features

**Capture a fiddler trace while opening the SharePoint designer and you should see a 505 error with the below error tag:**

```
<errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">Failed to find the XML file at location
     '14\Template\Features\custom solution\feature.xml'</errorstring><errorcode
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x80131600</errorcode></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

This is due to the feature which is not available at '14\Template\Features'. If you have a custom solution whose web parts are placed in a web site and the solution files are missing or the solution is retracted, you see this error.

**Solution:**

Remove the web parts that the solution adds to a site collection using PowerShell/code or deploy the solution back to the farm to get the feature.xml.

Read more about this:

[Unable to load workflow actions from the server. Please contact your server administrator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/archive/blogs/rajbugga/unable-to-load-workflow-actions-from-the-server-please-contact-your-server-administrator)

[SharePoint Designer 2010 - “Unable to load workflow actions from the server…”](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34405/sharepoint-designer-2010-unable-to-load-workflow-actions-from-the-server)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks similar to another post:
[SharePoint Designer 2010 - "Unable to load workflow actions from the server..."](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34405/sharepoint-designer-2010-unable-to-load-workflow-actions-from-the-server)

The gist of it is to check the ULS logs for "FetchLegalWorkflowActions" to help identify why you're getting the issue.

Comment: yes I read that post but that wasn't the problem with me. I finally  figured it out and one of the installed features is missing a .xml file. After I copied that .xml file, everything is back to normal. Thanks.